# Transfer funds without accessing to JSON wallet

Tags: ether

My question cause by my potention misunderstanding of how network works. Situation: I have my wallet number (only number) and its password. Can I (and how) transfer amount from this wallet to any other address? Or I must provide JSON wallet/key phrase/etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by wallet number? Do you mean your wallet address? And by password, do you mean your private key, or the password to decrypt your private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a few words no. To create a transaction sending your funds to someone else you have to cryptographically sign the transaction data with your private key, which is inside the JSON wallet file encrypted with your password.

Comment: Ok, got it. Am I right that if I have private key I can create transaction (as I remember called raw tranaction) and the sign it? So finally I do not need to JSON wallet?

Comment: Yes, if you have the private key you can sign transaction and do not need the json file. The wallet file is only a security measure to not store the private key uncrypted on disk.